# How do negated patterns work in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am attempting to use a .gitignore file with negated patterns (lines starting with !), but it's not working the way I expect.

As a minimal example, I have the folllowing directory structure:

```
C:/gittest
 -- .gitignore
 -- aaa/
   -- bbb/
     -- file.txt
   -- ccc/
     -- otherfile.txt
```

and in my gitignore file, I have this:

```
aaa/
!aaa/ccc/
```

My understanding (based on [this doc page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)) is that the file aaa/ccc/otherfile.txt should not be ignored, but in fact git is ignoring everything under aaa.

Am I misunderstanding this sentence: "An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again."?

BTW, this is on Windows with msysgit 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

I think that what you actually want to do is:

```
aaa/*
!aaa/ccc
```

You're telling it "don't look in `aaa`" so it never even examines the path `aaa/ccc`. If you use the wildcard, it still reads the contents of `aaa`, then each entry matches the wildcard and is ignored, except `aaa/ccc` which gets put back in.

Comment: This didn't work for me either:
/apps/*
!/apps/myApps/FluidTest/bin/

Comment: @Jarrod It does work; you're just doing something different. You'll have to use this method recursively, for exactly the reasons given in the answer. !apps/myApps, apps/myApps/* and so on.

Comment: Wonder why it doesn't work for aaa/**/* !aaa/ccc/eee (ignore everything, except files at certain path)

Comment: Same concept apply for subdirectories : ignore aaa/**/*, so never read content of aaa/ccc/*, so never matches !aaa/ccc/eee -- the same for  !/apps/myApps/FluidTest/bin/ . To ignore everything but a specific subfolder you have to reignore and unignore all level of the tree this way : (aaa/* !aaa/ccc aaa/ccc/*  !aaa/ccc/eee) (/apps/* !/apps/myApps /apps/myApps/* !/apps/myApps/FluidTest /apps/myApps/FluidTest/* !/apps/myApps/FluidTest/bin).  **[See examples in action](https://gitlab.com/celinederoland/draft-gitignore-negated-patterns)**

Answer (score 29):

If you want to exclude everything in `aaa`, but include `aaa/ccc` and everything beneath it, you should use:

```
aaa/*
!aaa/ccc
!aaa/ccc/*
```

The first line tells git to ignore everthing beneath `aaa`, the second tells it not to ignore the folder `aaa/ccc` which actually "enables" the third line which then tells it not to ignore everything beneath `aaa/ccc`.

Comment: The third line made no difference for me.

Comment: To be able to include everything in any subdirectory of `aaa/ccc` at any level, what worked for me was `!aaa/ccc/**` instead of `!aaa/ccc/*`

Answer (score 6):

If anyone's still not seeing newly un-ignored items in a `git status` running a `git update-index` before hand can help git to see the changes (at least in version 1.9.x of gitbash).