# .gitignore rules not working

Tags: gitignore

I'm in the process of building a Lemonstand site, which I'm managing via git. As such, I'm using the following .gitignore rules:

```
# Lemonstand
.htaccess
php.ini
boot.php
index.php
install.php
/config/*
/controllers/*
/init/*
/logs/*
/phproad/*
/temp/*
/uploaded/*
/installer_files/*
/modules/backend/*
/modules/blog/*
/modules/cms/*
/modules/core/*
/modules/session/*
/modules/shop/*
/modules/system/*
/modules/users/*
# add content_*.php if you don't want erase client changes to content

/modules/gallery/*
/modules/lddevel/*
/modules/tweak/*
```

(The top block [I got from github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/LemonStand.gitignore), with the second block being some additional rules I added myself to avoid issues with Lemonstands updating system).

My problem is that I'm adding a custom invoice to Lemonstand, which (to cut a long story short) requires the addition of a folder and some files within `/modules/shop/invoice_templates/`, which I've named `cm_standard`.

Because this is extra to the default Lemonstand, I want to get this tracked with git, so I'm trying to use the following rule to the bottom of my gitignore file:

```
!/modules/shop/invoice_templates/cm_standard/*
```

But when I do a `git add -A`, it isn't picking up the files within that directory. Even if I do a `git add modules/shop/invoice_templates/cm_standard/*` it tells me:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
modules/shop/invoice_templates
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Which further suggests I've not written the rule correctly - can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Would `!/modules/shop/invoice_templates/cm_standard/` works better? (without the last '`*`')

Comment: @VonC - tried that too, didn't work. cm_standard is a directory, rather than a file, I'm not sure if I made that clear in my original question which is why I've got the * on the end.

Comment: When you want to ignore directory content, you never need the '`*`': remove all your '`*`' and check if that work better (keep the last '/' though, for each directory)

Comment: @VonC Removing the stars didn't hurt - but it also didn't help.

Comment: Ok just making sure here. I will test on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore patterns with fewer path segments can take precedence over patterns with more path segments, so in your case `/modules/shop/*` is taking precedence over `!/modules/shop/invoice_templates/cm_standard/*`, effectively pruning the whole of `/modules/shop/invoice_templates/` from the directory traversal even before it looks at the contents of  `!/modules/shop/invoice_templates/cm_standard`.  Having said that, ordering can matter too, and when it does, somewhat counter-intuitively later rules within a file take precedence over earlier ones.

This question is very similar to [How do gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001888/how-do-gitignore-exclusion-rules-actually-work) so I suggest you read that.  Also you may find the `check-ignore` subcommand useful  when [debugging rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file) - I added it to git over the last few months and it just appeared in version 1.8.2 which was released a few days ago.