# Changes to gitignore are not being applied

Tags: git, gitignore

I have multile projects in an folder being tracked by git. My original .gitignore contained nothing but * to ignore everything except a `*.java` in some projects. Now I am starting another project and I have added or rather included it in .gitignore file to track them but when making commit git tells me `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:`. I could use `-f` to force track the project files but I am wondering why git is not applying changes I have made to `.gitignore`.

My original .gitignore.

```
.gitignore
# Ignore everything
*

# Except for these files
!Assignment1/
!Assignment1/*.java
!Assignment2/
!Assignment2/*.java
!Assignment3/
!Assignment3/*.java
!Assignment4/
!Assignment4/*.java
!Assignment5/
!Assignment5/*.java
!Assignment6/                                                                                                                                                          
!Assignment6/*.java
!README.md
```

My current .gitignore. You can see that now I want to track all .java files in Assignment7.

```
.gitignore
# Ignore everything
*

# Except for these files
!Assignment1/
!Assignment1/*.java
!Assignment2/
!Assignment2/*.java
!Assignment3/
!Assignment3/*.java
!Assignment4/
!Assignment4/*.java
!Assignment5/
!Assignment5/*.java
!Assignment6/                                                                                                                                                          
!Assignment6/*.java
!Assignment7/                                                                                                                                                          
!Assignment7/*.java
!README.md
```

After adding `!Assignment7/` and `!Assignment7/*.java`, when I run `git add .` or `git add -A` the commands run without any problem but the Assignment7 files are not tracked.

```
[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git add .
[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git add -A
[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Trying to add the files by adding location tells following

```
[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git add Assignment7
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Assignment7
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
[donnie@fedora workspace]$ git add Assignment7/*.java
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Assignment7/FacePamphlet.java
Assignment7/FacePamphletCanvas.java
Assignment7/FacePamphletConstants.java
Assignment7/FacePamphletDatabase.java
Assignment7/FacePamphletProfile.java
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

I can solve this problem by adding -f but I would like know what am I missing. Why am I not able to track files that are added to be un-exluded from .gitignore files.

Thanks.

Edit:- Similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090726/gitignore-rules-not-working) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001888/how-do-gitignore-exclusion-rules-actually-work) were not so helpful as .git reside in top-directory and files to be tracked are in sub-directories.

Comment: What happens if you use patterns to *ignore* the files you don't want, rather than ignoring everything and then "opting back in" with some files?  This is the normal use-case for `.gitignore`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Since I want to ignore everything except *.java, I went ignore everything route. Even if your suggestion works, it will require me to investigate all files and folders in the workspace and add them to .gitignore manually. It doesn't look like an ideal solution to me at this point of time.

Comment: So why not ignore everything and then use `!*.java`?

Comment: @trojanfoe isn't that exactly what I have done?

Comment: You did it for each directory, what you could do is just
* \n
!*.java

Comment: @frant.hartm I imported these files into Eclipse but want git to track them as I worked on them. It would not have harmed to do as you but it also doesn't solve the problem at hand. Also there are some test folders with *.java files in that workspace which I don't want to be tracked and hence per folder structure better suited me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The following paths are ignored by one of your `.gitignore` files:

To know more and understand which rule of which `gitignore` file is the cause for that message, use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- Assignment7/FacePamphlet.java
```

More generally, you can use:

```
*
!/**/
!*.java
```