# gitignore ignoring .emacs.d even with !.emacs.d exception

Tags: git

This `.gitignore` doesn't ignore `.emacs.d`

```
.*
!.emacs.d
```

but the following **does** ignore it:

```
*  <- only change
.*
!.emacs.d
```

Why?

This is with `git-1.7.10-x86_64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `*` matches the current directory in which the file `.emacs.d` is.
And if a directory is ignored, git won't look inside at all (including for negate rules exceptions).

See, for more on that behavior:

- "[How do `gitignore` exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001967/6309)"
- "[`.gitignore` exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/6309)"

> If you exclude `aDirectory/`, then everything under it will always be excluded (even if some later negative exclusion pattern (“unignore”) might match something under `aDirectory/`).

The [OP user273158](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283296/user273158) asks:

> How can I then exclude all files and directories (hidden or not hidden) in a given path (e.g. my home directory), except `.emacs.d` (and other exceptions)

I suppose this should work better:

```
./*
!/.emacs.d
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I then exclude all files and directories (hidden or not hidden) in a given path (e.g. my home directory), except `.emacs.d` (and other exceptions)?

Comment: @user273158 I think that is precisely what shows the first link I reference in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3001967/6309