# Git Including an arbitrarily nested subfolder when its parent has been excluded in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitignore

I'm excluding a folder a and its subfolders, but want to have a specific subfolder b included, where b can be a subfolder somewhere below a, and the exact path to b has not been specified.

My `.gitignore` contains these lines:

```
a/**
!a/**/b
```

however this does not work. Have tried numerous other permutations of the above, including from other posts on stack overflow, but nothing appears to work.

The previous question on stackoverflow deals with the situation where you can explicitly declare the path to the subdirectory. In this question, the situation I'm addressing is where `b` can be any subfolder underneath `a`, and not a predetermined path.

Further the earlier solution requires you to "unignore" every parent directory of anything that you want to "unignore". However in this case I'm trying to create a generic rule that allows this subdirectory without bothering about where it is in the directory tree. So the earlier solution does not work/apply in this situation.

Comment: For everyone's convenience, could you add a link to the other question you're talking about?

Comment: This question is a duplicate because quite simply there's just *no better* solution, no alternative. You can either do what was posted there, or it cannot be done, no matter how many times you ask the same question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good point, here is a link the other question, which is different as the subfolder has a specific path rather than being generic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Comment: @Janos, the other question as I've already pointed out is different. Without asking how am I ever to know that what I'm asking "cannot be done". From what I've been reading I had thought it possible but wasn't able to get it to work, your's is the first that I've heard that its not possible.

Comment: @janos At least by my definitions of the words involved, "no better solution" is not quite the same thing as "duplicate question"...

Comment: I think I covered why it isn't possible in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tell git to ignore a directory, it will completely ignore everything inside that directory. This means git cannot match your exclude because git is simply not looking at it.

The only way to use excludes in a meaningful way is for a single directory, where you ignore everything but some folder like this:

```
/some/path/*
!/some/path/foo
```

This will ignore all entries but `foo` directly under `/some/path`.

But, most of the time it is much clearer to just explicitly ignore things than using excludes.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't scale to any path, as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9604395/6309: I just tested it on Windows with git1.8.4

Comment: I meant: **it does not work**, at least on Windows with 1.8.4. '`**/*`' will ignore everything, even with a negation rule just after it.

Comment: And it doesn't work because it is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded, as I mentioned before in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the files manually (generally this takes precedence over `.gitignore`-style rules):

```
git add /path/to/module
```

You may even want the `-N` *intent to add* flag, to suggest you *will* add them, but not immediately. I often do this for new files I’m not ready to stage yet.

---

This a [copy of an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56480861/457268) posted to a dupe of this question. I am reposting it here for increased visibility—I find it easier not to have a mess of gitignore rules.