# Whitelist folder inside ignored folder

Tags: node.js, git, node-modules, gitignore

I have a node.js project with some node_modules. Now a node_module was not upto expectations and I manually changed, compiled and put it back into the node_module folder.

I want to add this module to the GIT, however, the node_modules are listed in my gitignore (obviously).

I tried the following

`/node_modules
!/node_modules/the_module/**`

But files are not showing up when doing `git status`

Is it possible to whitelist one package inside a ignored folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+unignore+subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically the answer is:

```
/node_modules/*
!/node_modules/the_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the files manually (generally this takes precedence over `.gitignore`-style rules):

```
git add /path/to/module
```

You may even want the `-N` *intent to add* flag, to suggest you *will* add them, but not immediately. I often do this for new files I’m not ready to stage yet.