# How can I git unignore subfolders inside folder with some pattern name?

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I unignore every folder with name `config`? Recursively

For example I want to put my `/` under git. I put `*` in `.gitignore` to ignore everything. Now I want unignore folders and subfolders and subsubfolders... with name `config`.

Suppose I don't know full path to this `config` folders. I want something like: `!**/config/**`, but it doesn't work.

my `.gitignore`:

```
*
!**/config/**
```

May be someone suggests another way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3001888/1256452) (note in particular the last answer, that says that a directory is not even opened if it's already excluded).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.gitignore`:

```
*
!config/
```

You don't have to use asterisks to tell Git to work recursively.