# I know .gitignore works in one direction, but does it work in the reverse direction?

Tags: git

Trying to understand how `.gitignore` files work: do they just ignore files only when you push to a branch or do they also ignore the same files if they've been updated on master, and you want to pull those changes? I know it works in one direction: when I want to push to a remote branch, and I'm wondering if it works in the reverse direction: when I want to pull changes for a gitignore-d file from a remote branch.

Comment: So many duplicates and refs elsewhere https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001888/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/11451535/1531971 https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ (Show what research you've done and then re-ask in the context of all the reference material available to you.)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `.gitignore` works. The only job of the `.gitignore` file is to prevent you from adding them to the staging area. Thus, if you try to

```
git add file.txt
```

and `file.txt` is mentioned in the `.gitignore` file, you will get an error:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
file.txt
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

You can use the `-f` flag, as mentioned in the error message, to add the file anyways:

```
git add -f file.txt
```

This also implies that files that are already tracked by Git are not influenced by the `.gitignore` file anymore. More on that here: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1)