# gitignore include specific sub-directory from ignored/excluded directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I want ignore everything EXCEPT for one folder in my `node_modules`. So here is what I have put in my `.gitignore`:

```
!/node_modules/abc/*
/node_modules
```

Also tried:

```
!node_modules/abc/*
node_modules/*
```

But it is not working, as it is supposed to. This is making every folder inside `node_modules` getting ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation needs to be:

Ignore everything in node modules (note the trailing wildcard - this is important because otherwise, it just ignores the whole node_modules folder, and will not evaluate your nested folder, which you will un-ignore in the next line):

`node_modules/*`

**EXCEPT**:

`!node_modules/abc/*`

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/abc/*
```

> The * is important as otherwise you're ignoring the directory itself (so git won't look inside) instead of the files within the directory (which allows for the exclusion).

[How do .gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001888/how-do-gitignore-exclusion-rules-actually-work)

[.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do so in a .gitignore inside the node_modules directory, because it is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. See the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: The OP ignored `node_modules` so `.gitignore` inside the `node_modules` is not considered at all.

Comment: @phd Right. So instead of that, he needs to ignore everything from inside `node_modules` except that one thing he wants.