# Is there an order of precedence in GitIgnore files when excluding file types?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a large project with a global .gitignore file. It is set up to ignore all files by default, with manual exceptions. One of those exceptions is all .txt files, which is set up with !*.txt

I have a txt file that I want ignored, but I still want the rule to ignore all txts except this specific file. If the file name is foo.txt, I know I have to add foo.txt somewhere in the .gitignore file. should I add it before or after the rule !*.txt? Does it matter?

Tried to add it to the start, and it does not ignore my file. Also tried to add it to the end, and it still does not ignore my file

Comment: Related: [How do .gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001888/11082165) and [Explain which gitignore rule is ignoring my file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144633/11082165)

Comment: Is the file that you want to ignore already tracked by Git?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "It is set up to ignore all files by default"? That could mean one of several things, with a _huge_ difference between them. In particular, if "ignore all files" is actually "ignore all top directories", then git won't ever get the chance to recurse down to process re-inclusions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do .gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001888/how-do-gitignore-exclusion-rules-actually-work)