# gitignore android include the apk

Tags: android, eclipse, git, gitignore

In my repository I want to exclude all the binary files, all the generated files etc. But I do want to include the final apk file. I picked up the standard gitignore for android(see [here](https://gist.github.com/4388441/revisions)) and changed it according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder). But now it is not ignoring the bin/res folder. Of course I can add another line to manually exclude bin/res also but that does not seem standard. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `apk` file is only present in the bin/ directory, you could try:

```
bin/
!*.apk
```

This would be similar to the setting described in "[How do gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001967/6309)".

What you tried is similar to "[How do negated patterns work in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820310/6309)", and this might work:

```
bin/*
!bin/*.apk
bin/res/
```