# How To Not ignore based on keyword in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Because I'm using microsoft nuget, I want to ignore all the package directories in my projects (there are a huge number of these and those files are all temporary).  Unfortunately, in the JavaScript library I also have in the same repository, I need the package directory.  So, I have in my .gitignore

```
...
package
...
```

But, in my directory

```
/JavaScript/package/importantfiles
```

I want to not ignore this file.

How can I let all "package" get ignored, but in the directory /JavaScript/... I want package to be included in source control?

Comment: Have you tried `!/JavaScript/package`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820255/how-do-negated-patterns-work-in-gitignore

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that:

> [It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309) (`*`)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.8+, see below)

It means that you need to ignore package folder *files* in order to un-ignore one of those files:

```
package/*
!importantFile
```

---

Note that with git 2.8.x/2.9 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0.

So in your case, this would work:

```
/JavaScript/package
!/JavaScript/package/importantfiles
```