# Opposite of .git/info/exclude - including files that are excluded by .gitignore

Tags: git, version-control, version, versioning

Is there a way to include files specifically excluded by a projects .gitignore file? Similar to how .git/info/exclude listings exclude files while not being under version control I want to revert exclusions done by .gitignore so I can see changes in these files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do negated patterns work in .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820255/how-do-negated-patterns-work-in-gitignore)

Comment: @Ben Nelson, have you get the answer what you want? If yes, please mark it, and it will help for latecomers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding files in `.gitignore`, there are four statuses of files:

1. Untracked
2. deleted
3. staged but modified
4. staged with no changes

so you can use:
`git ls-files -o` to list untracked files
`git ls-files -d` to list deleted files by the last operation
`git ls-files -m` to list modified files
`???` to list files have been staged

Comment: @Marina_Liu note that "git ls-files -s" does NOT list files that have been staged.  Per the docs, it will "Show staged contents' mode bits, object name and stage number in the output."

Answer (score 1):

Yes: just add them (edit: with `git add -f`). The ignore specs only apply when scanning for untracked files (or when explicitly working with the ignore criteria, `git ls-files` can e.g. show you tracked files that match ignore criteria).

Comment: actually, that might not be 100% what i'm looking for. i more want to list files as untracked since they are not things i necessarily want to include in my commit but i want to be notified of their presence in the repository. sorry on the confusion!

Comment: You can list files matching any pattern(s) you want, `git ls-files` has an `--exclude-per-directory` feature that allows you to construct and track arbitrary `.gitignore`-style selections for file names, you can use them yourself any way you want, but `git status` and such only use the standard exclusions.