# Exclude/include folders without contents using gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am currently trying to exclude all contents of those 3 folders but keep the folders themselfs:

[image]

- files/*
- files/private/*
- files/tmp/*

But for now just the files directory gets included.
This is what my .gitignore looks like:

```
default-export/files/*
default-export/files/private/*
default-export/files/tmp/*

!default-export/files/.gitkeep
!default-export/files/private/.gitkeep
!default-export/files/tmp/.gitkeep
```

Comment: I see. So, you are trying to Preserve the Directory Structure while keeping the Files hidden? So that the other developer could have the same directory structure, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need this for a automated test setup.

Comment: Per git docs, "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded." Once you exclude `default-export/files/*`, which will exclude `default-export/files/private` and `default-export/files/tmp` directories, you cannot re-include `default-export/files/private/.gitkeep` and `default-export/files/tmp/.gitkeep`. EDIT: [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/240443).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Alternately, just ignore the whole `files` directory, and force-add (`git add -f`) the `.gitkeep` files. Once the files are added, `.gitignore` has no power over them.

Comment: @amadan, Tried that, sadly didnt work :)

Comment: @Zeta: Hm isnt that exactly what I have described within my question?

Comment: @Basti You only have a top-level `.gitignore`, if I'm not mistaken. The linked question suggests a `.gitignore` *per directory* that shall be left empty.

Comment: `/default-export/files` in `.gitignore` and `git add -f **/.gitkeep && git commit` definitely works, I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the explicit un-excludes of the directories `private` and `tmp`. Without them, Git does not further process the directory structure at all.

This should work according to your described requirements:

```
default-export/files/*
!default-export/files/.gitkeep
!default-export/files/private/
!default-export/files/tmp/

default-export/files/private/*
!default-export/files/private/.gitkeep

default-export/files/tmp/*
!default-export/files/tmp/.gitkeep
```

Comment: That does not work; files without extension still get listed due to `*.*`. Are you sure about that pattern? (Note that it might work for OP, if all their files have an extension)

Comment: @Zeta I edited my answer which now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I shall like to clarify that the Folders don't hold great significance for Git.
Simply speaking, they are just considered as "Links" to the files inside it.

Hence, an empty directory can't be staged.

In some cases, in order to preserve the directory structure, the directory needs to be added. The same can be achieved by placing a dummy file inside it.

Over the years, the dummy file has received the name `.gitkeep` (You can name it anything you want to. `.` is for hiding the same in a LINUX/UNIX System).

## Solution to your Problem

You need to create the `.gitkeep` file and then, add the following lines to your `.gitignore`.

```
theEmptyDirectory/*

!.gitkeep
```

Here is the directory structure I used to test the same
[image]

`thisIsAPrivateFile` represents the content I want to keep private while maintaining the directory structure.

And the `git status` (After staging) result.
[image]

As you can clearly see, `thisIsAPrivateFile` has not been staged.

## UPDATE

After Matt's comment, I shall like to inform a certain limitation of `git`.
[image]

Basically, if the parent directory has been excluded, no matter what, any files inside the same can't be included. Since, in the above example, I have excluded everything (even nested directories) using `*` then, everything inside those nested directories won't be included.

We can *bypass* this limitation by specifying the types of files we want to exclude.

Here is the new directory structure

[image]

Updated `.gitignore`

```
theEmptyDirectory/**/*.js
theEmptyDirectory/**/*.jsx
theEmptyDirectory/**/*.ts

!.gitkeep
```

And the `git status` result (After Staging)
[image]

Clearly, the directory structured has been preserved but, the private files have been exluded.

## References

- [Difference Between `.gitignore` and `.gitkeep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885/what-are-the-differences-between-gitignore-and-gitkeep)
- [Negating Patterns in `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820255/how-do-negated-patterns-work-in-gitignore)
- [Internal Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)
- [Reading on `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: The question is not just about a single folder but a nested folder structure where all contents of the parent folder of two subfolders should be excluded as well.

Comment: @Matt Yes, thank you for pointing out the same. I have updated the answer to include a workaround for the same.

Comment: The workaround does not handle files without extension, even when specifying `*.*`.

Comment: The mentioned limitation actually is the underlying problem why it did not work for @Basti. But this limitation does not apply when you explicitly un-exclude the parent directory as I do in my answer.

Comment: I see. `*.*` won't work as the pattern clearly has  a `.` so, it will only work on `abc.` and not `abc`.

Comment: So, now Basti has two solutions: Either to explicitly include and exclude directories or, specify a type for even for extensionless files. E.G: `_IamExtensionLess`.