# How to .gitignore all files/folder in a folder, but not the folder itself?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to check in a blank folder to my Git repository. Effectively, I need to ignore all of the files and folders within the folder, but not the folder itself. How can I do this? What should I put in my `.gitignore` file?

For those wondering why I would want to do this, I have an "upload" directory in my repository. I want to commit the blank directory, but without all the contents.

Comment: I had exactly the same thing. Just added a README file to that explaining that this is the upload directory and git understood it :)

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question: put a .gitignore which says "ignore everything" into that folder; this  is mipadi's answer.

Comment: This is useful to put empty build folder in git. No content inside build folder needs to be checked in

Comment: I still can't believe Git has no way to do this properly. SVN can do it.

Comment: I know this has been marked as a duplicate but just for the sake of completeness and for those reading this in the future: [Git does not version folders](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F). The typical workaround is to include a `.gitkeep` or `.keep` file in the folder you want to version.

Comment: I've developed a [helper tool for this which you can find in here](https://github.com/mig82/py-gitkeep). You can install it running `pip3 install gitkeep2` and then run `gitkeep --recursive path/to/foo` to keep folder `foo` and all its subfolders. It also allows you to comment those `.gitkeep` files and remove them recursively or not.

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

You can't commit empty folders in git. If you want it to show up, you need to put something in it, even just an empty file.

For example, add an empty file called `.gitkeep` to the folder you want to keep, then in your `.gitignore` file write:

```
# exclude everything
somefolder/*

# exception to the rule
!somefolder/.gitkeep
```

Commit your `.gitignore` and `.gitkeep` files and this should resolve your issue.

Comment: isnt there a `--bare` option?

Comment: The best way is as listed above by Trianam. Include a .gitignore file at the dir. This .gitignore should ignore all files inside that dir (*), except itself (!.gitignore).

Comment: Only commit and empty folder dose not solve the issue of be sure files in this folder will never be traked. Better to use a .gitignore  file as @Trianam showed below.

Comment: @LeandroAlves creating a.gitignore file inside of each directory is bad practice at all...

Comment: Is there a reason why putting `somefolder/` (without a star) in .gitignore would override later negation and would not not include .gitkeep?

Comment: this does not work

Comment: @kubi what is the difference betw: `.gitignore` vs `.gitkeep` ?
I'm aware that a `.gitignore` file explicity instructs `git` to avoid staging certain files/folders.
cc: @LeandroAlves

Comment: this was not working for me until I added a forward slash in front of the folder name like this `/content/folder/*` I also had to do this, but for some users it may not be necessary https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/11439685

Comment: works for me. And @Sumax .gitkeep is a standard file name meant to prevent the deletion of purposely empty folders

Comment: how to ignore specific folder that can have any path on any folder? For example, user/cache, project/folder/system/cache.. I need to ignore this "cache" folder.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper to ignore content and subdirectories: `**/cache/*`
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/how-to-git-ignore-subfolders-subdirectories#:~:text=To%20exclude%20content%20and%20subdirectories%3A)

Answer (score 1783):

Put this `.gitignore` into the folder, then `git add .gitignore`.

```
*
!.gitignore
```

The `*` line tells git to ignore all files in the folder, but `!.gitignore` tells git to still include the `.gitignore` file. This way, your local repository and any other clones of the repository all get both the empty folder and the `.gitignore` it needs.

Comment: Ignoring directories `*/` is not necessary because `*` also covers directories.

Comment: [NB](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) «It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.»

Comment: Workaround for @TimofeyGorshkov's point above: `* ; !dir/ ; dir/* ; !dir/reincludefile`

Comment: One should note, the second `.gitignore` does not need to named that. Any `filename` will do as long as the file's contents include `!filename`. I mention this because we thought having a `.gitignore` file which functions to keep a directory seemed misleading and unclear.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Really, the best solution so far.

Comment: Why is this 'the best solution'... `.gitkeep` was literally designed for this?

Comment: `*` ignores all files and directories, sub-files and sub-directories, ...etc. I think this will work the same way `*; !*/`, which ignores all files and includes all directories which will be ignored as well because there are no non-ignored files in them. After that you can include any file you want `!dir/reincludefile`