# gitignore files on specified folder but folders must be tracked

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore

I want to `gitignore` all files inside my `public/images/Users/` directory but I want that path to be tracked on my repository so that other collaborators will not create new folders on their machines.
I have this line on my `.gitignore` file `public/images/Users/*` but this line ignores all from images folder. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks. By the way, my project is on `Laravel` framework.

Comment: Git doesn't track directories at all. They get created as needed to hold files. I have voted to close this question as a duplicate, as this has already been asked and answered dozens of times on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track directories but not their files with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091017/how-to-track-directories-but-not-their-files-with-git)

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the [practice of adding placeholder files in folders you want cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5091017/6309) (but with an ignored content), consider that the [laravel project](http://github.com/laravel/laravel/) uses an original variation of that technique:

See the [`laravel/app/storage/logs`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/storage/logs) folder.

The `.gitignore` itself is the placeholder file which allows its parent folder to be versioned.

But [its content](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/storage/logs/.gitignore) is:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

It ignores every file within the `logs` folder, except for itself.