# How to write .gitignore, so that a directory is put in git, but not its contents

Tags: git

Say I have a directory ...`/parent`, containing various files and subdirectories. One of this subdirectories is `/parent/slave`

I would like to have all the files in ...`/parent/slave` git-ignored, but not the directory `slave` itself - i.e., someone cloning the git repository, would always find an empty slave directory.

What do I have to put into `.gitignore` to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250063/how-to-gitignore-all-files-folder-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just about what you want by adding a .gitignore to the ../parent/slave directory with contents such as:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

If that doesn't do what you're after, the other answers here may be helpful:

[How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)