# How do I use .gitignore in a folder?

Tags: git

I have an img folder within my git repository. I want to use .gitignore to exclude the images within the folder.

I used `cd <file path>` to enter that folder and `mkdir .gitignore`. But when I `add` the git the images are not excluded. What do I need to add to keep them excluded from the `add`?

Comment: Can you show what the contents of your .gitignore file are?

Comment: .gitignore must be a file as described in the answers and not a directory as it is if you did `mkdir .gitignore`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file does not have any effect only by its mere presence. An empty `.gitignore` file is just an empty file, nothing more.

`Git` reads the content of the `.gitignore` file and uses the patterns it contains to decide what files to put in the repo and what files to ignore. Read more about [the format of `.gitignore` files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Contrary to what other answers to this question state, you **can** have a `.gitignore` file in any directory of your repository, not only in the root directory.

When it decides how to handle a new file (track it or ignore it) it combines the information from multiple `gitignore` sources:

- the command line;
- the `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the file and the `.gitingore` files in their parent directories inside the repo;
- the local repository ignore file (not pushed to the remote repos) `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`;
- the global ignore file specified in `~/.gitconfig`; it applies to all local repository of the user.

Back to your concrete situation, if you want to tell `Git` to ignore the files in the `img` directory you can put `*` in the file `img/.gitignore`.

Another option is to put `<path-to-img>/*` in the `.gitignore` file on the root directory of your repo. Replace `<path-to-img>` with the actual path from the root of the repo to the `img` file.

The content of the file `.gitignore` is used only by `git add`. If a file is already in the repository, adding in `.gitignore` a pattern that matches its name doesn't make `Git` ignore it from now on. It must be manually removed from the repo (and the removal committed), otherwise `Git` will continue to track its content.

In your situation, the commands to run are along these lines:

```
cd <path-to-img-directory>
echo "*" >> .gitignore
git rm *
git add .gitignore
git commit
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `.gitignore` file *should* be in the repository's root directory to start with. It becomes easier to manage that way. You can then place separate `.gitignore` files in the subdirectories where you need to *override* the patterns defined in the root `.gitignore` file.

To exclude the `img` directory, simply add this line to `.gitignore`:

```
img/
```

If you want to make the exclusion *case-insensitive*, you can instead write:

```
[Ii]mg/
```

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the
>   following description, but it would only find a match with a
>   directory. In other words, `foo/` will match a directory `foo` and paths
>   underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link
>   `foo`.

As an aside, you can list the files that are currently ignored in your repository by using the [`git-ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) command:

```
git ls-files --ignored --others --exclude-standard
```

where the `--exclude-standard` option tells Git to consider the patterns defined in the `.git/info/exclude` file, the repository's `.gitignore` file (both in the root directory and in all of the subdirectories) as well as the global `.gitignore` file.

Comment: It is possible to place the .gitignore file within the subdirectory, right?  It doesn't "need" to be in the root directory?

Comment: Correct – you can have `.gitignore` files in the subdirectories as well. I didn't say it _has to_ be in the root directory but it becomes easier to manage if you start with that. You can then place other `.gitignore` files in the subdirectories where you need to _override_ the settings defined in the root one.

Comment: Perfect, just wanted to check.  The wording originally was "you should place" and that is what I wanted to check,

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `.gitignore` file within your git repository (place the file in your root folder - It is easier to manage all your untracked files/folders this way) and add your img folder to that file.

Create a `.gitignore` file

open the file and add this line:

```
img/
```

to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the .gitignore file in your folder  and add * to specify that all files in it should be ignored.
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250063/how-to-gitignore-all-files-folder-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself)