# gitignore not ignoring config files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250063/how-to-gitignore-all-files-folder-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) but they do not seem to be working for me.

I have a `git` project with the following directory structure:

```
myapp/
    src/
    .gitignore
    build/
```

Where the `myapp/.gitignore` is:

```
### gitignore ###
build/
```

I now need to add a top-level `config` directory, and would like to add config files to it for local development/testing purposes, but do not want them committed. I only want the ("empty") `config` directory committed. So I read those two questions above and tried implementing their advice. Now my project looks like:

```
myapp/
    src/
    .gitignore
    build/
    config/
        .gitignore
        test.json
```

Where `myapp/.gitignore` is:

```
### gitignore ###
build/
!config/.gitignore
```

And where `config/.gitignore` is just:

```
!.gitignore
```

However when I do a `git add . -n` (dry run) I see:

```
add '.gitignore'
add 'config/.gitignore'
add 'config/test.json'
```

...so it looks like its going to try and add my `test.json` config file anyways. I just want it to add the config directory, so that the command would output:

```
add '.gitignore'
add 'config/.gitignore'
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry (and why)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config/.gitignore` should contain:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

That is, "ignore everything *but* `.gitignore`." This:

```
!.gitignore
```

Just says "don't ignore `.gitignore`", but it doesn't say that anything else *should* be ignored.

(You also don't need `!config/.gitignore` in the root `.gitignore` file.)