# gitignore file is ignoring the wrong directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a simple directory structure:

```
gitroot/
└── docker/
    └── critical_dependencies/
```

I would like to just ignore the entire contents of the `critical_dependencies/` directory. My `.gitignore` file has the following entry:

```
docker/critical_dependencies/*
```

It doesn't seem to be ignoring any of the folders that are in that directory. What is the proper way to ask the `.gitignore` file to ignore everything from a sub-directory?

Comment: check this, seems similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Comment: Couldn't get any of the suggestions from that post to work @AmreshS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure .gitignore file is in the working directory. It doesn't work if you put it in the .git (repository) directory.

`cd` to the directory where the .gitignore file is. Or your usual root directory of the project. Check the path of your **critical dependencies** folder from here.

Then do a `cat .gitignore` and add your exact path to the file like so:

```
docker/critical_dependencies/
```

It should work.

Git does not display empty directories - so if you need a workaround, look at the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250063/how-to-gitignore-all-files-folder-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself).

A similar issue is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this, and the critical_dependencies directory is still not showing up in my repo. It's like git ignored it once, and won't 'forget' that it was ignored previously.

Comment: @wandadars Oh wait - your issue is that, even if the directory is not there in the .gitignore file, it is still being ignored?

Comment: If I take any reference to it out of the .gitignore file, then it shows up again and I can add it along with all of the subdirectories within in(the stuff I want to ignore). The trouble is that if I add that line, it just completely ignores the entire critical_dependencies directory.  If I commit my changes and push them to a remote repo, that directory doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused - you want the subdirectories or files inside critical_dependencies to be ignored, but not the directory itself. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah. critical_dependencies holds a bunch of folders with shared objects in them, and I would like to just ignore everything such that when someone clones the repo the critical_dependencies directory is completely empty.

Comment: For some reason git won't include an empty directory. I added a junk.txt file to the critical_dependencies directory, and now it is seeing it.

Comment: @wandadars Yes, you are right, but there is a workaround - I have updated my answer for this - check it out :)

Comment: That is a bit frustrating. Thank you for following through to get to the answer @learning.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

just add this to .gitgnore docker/critical_dependencies/ it should work as the files already added remove them with git rm -r --cached docker/critical_dependencies/*

Comment: I would like to keep the critical_dependencies directory. For some reason that directory is being ignored now.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove (with `git rm --cached`) any existing tracked files before your `.gitignore` does you any good.  After that, you can create a file:

```
gitroot/docker/critical_dependencies/.gitignore
```

containing the two lines:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

in that order, and then add and commit it.  See below for why.

(I'm assuming that when you said `gitroot` you meant you have a directory literally named `gitroot`.  If not, take `gitroot/` out of this path.)

#### Description

There are a few things you need to know about Git before you can do anything sensible with `.gitignore` files.

First, Git doesn't track directories at all.  Git only stores *files*.  If the file's path name is `d1/d2/file.ext`, Git will *create* directories `d1` and `d1/d2` if it must, so that `file.ext` can live in them; but Git remembers nothing at all *about* `d1` and `d1/d2`, it just knows that they must *be* there so that `file.ext` can *live* there.

Second, a file is *tracked* in Git if and only if it is in the index *right now*.  But you can't *see* the index—at least, not with normal commands.  If you want to see what's in the index right now, use `git ls-files` (with `--stage` to see even more).  Note that `git ls-files` starts from your current directory, whatever that is, so it is a good idea to be in the top level directory of whatever you care about at the time (e.g., the root of your project to see *everything*).  But this command is not usually very useful: it's usually more interesting to *compare* what's in the index with something else.  It's mainly useful when you have a stubborn, tough case and want to see what's *really* in the index.

(Side note: *the index* contains *the files that will be in the **next** commit you make.*  When you run `git add d1/d2/file.ext` you are telling Git to copy that file from the work-tree, where you can edit it and use it, *into* the index.  If there was a copy in the index before, this updates the copy.  If not, this puts a new one into the index.  In either case, the *next* commit will now have the latest version of the file.  After you run `git commit`, the index *still has all those files*, in the same form that they were when you ran `git commit`.  So all those files are, by definition, tracked: **a file is tracked if and only if it is in the index.**)

Now, with that out of the way, we can look at what `.gitignore` really does.  *It does not make Git ignore files.*  What it does is make Git *stop complaining about* files, and *avoid copying those files into the index if they're not already in the index.*

In other words, **if a file is tracked, it cannot be ignored.**

**If a file is untracked, it is not in the index.  If that untracked file is *also* marked "ignored", Git won't complain about it and won't add it *to* the index.**  And that's most of what `.gitignore` is about: untracked files listed in a `.gitignore` become both untracked *and* ignored, but tracked files are unaffected.

That, finally, brings us to the answer:

> I would like to just ignore the entire contents of the `critical_dependencies` directory.

In this case, you can create a file named `.gitignore` *in* that directory:

```
gitroot/docker/critical_dependencies/.gitignore
```

The contents of this file can be just:

```
*
```

(one line consisting of a single asterisk), but this is a bit better for several reasons:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

This says "ignore everything in this directory ... but wait a minute, don't ignore `.gitignore` though; ignore everything *except* `.gitignore`".

Next, you need to make sure that *this* file *is* in the index.  That way it will be in the *next* commit that you make.  The content we just put in it is the right content as well, so let's `git add` it:

```
git add gitroot/docker/critical_dependencies/.gitignore
```

Now you know why we said "don't ignore `.gitignore`": we *want* `git add` to copy it into the index even though it's not there yet, so we tell `git add` that this particular file *isn't* one we want kept out of the index.

Once it's actually *in* the index—we could force this to happen even without the `!.gitignore` line—it won't matter if the contents say to ignore it, because it will be *tracked* at that point and its contents will have no effect on it.  But this makes it easy to get it *into* the index the first time.

Moreover, it means that if we clone the repository and check out this particular commit, Git has to write the file:

```
gitroot/docker/critical_dependencies/.gitignore
```

somewhere, and to do that, Git has to *create* the directory.  So you get your directory created.

Unfortunately, we *also* need to make sure that *no other* files in that directory, or any sub-directory of that directory, are in the index.  So now we need to slowly, painfully, `git rm` every such file, as listed by `git ls-files` while you're in that directory.

***But wait!***, you might object, ***Won't that remove the files from the work-tree too?***

Yes, it will.  Sucks, doesn't it? :-)

You can avoid that right now using `git rm --cached`.  That tells Git to remove these from the index without touching the work-tree.  But if you ever `git checkout` a commit that *has* all these files, they will go into your index.  Your index holds whatever you checked out, so that it will go into the *next* commit you make, on a new branch starting from this old commit.  You can then `git checkout` a later commit that *doesn't* have these files, and Git will remove them ... which, well, *removes* them.

This is why you want to be careful never to add a file that you should not have added.  Once you do, you have some commits permanently saved in your repository that will make those files tracked, if you check out those commits.  Go from one such commit to another commit that doesn't have the files, and they'll become untracked again, but they'll get that way because Git will remove them from both the index *and* the work-tree.

#### A final shortcut (though it's just as painful for future work)

Instead of manually running `git rm --cached` on every file, we can switch the order of creating and adding the `.gitignore` file:

```
$ cd gitroot/docker/critical_dependencies/
$ git rm -r --cached .
```

and *then* create the `.gitignore` file with the two lines and `git add` and `git commit` it.