# Subfolders in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have many subfolders in my repo, in which there are few `build/` directories I'd like to ignore when committing my code. As I understand it, there are two ways to ignore all of the folders:

- `*/build/` (Unix wildcards)
- `build/` (*git* way of ignoring files/folders)

I've found [Git ignore sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/git-ignore-sub-folders) but it has two answers and I would like to know **what the difference (none?) between the two approaches is**. Does the same rule apply to files?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`build/` is the right way to do it. It will ignore any files that are inside `build` directories no matter how deep are these directories nested in your repo.

`*/build/` means ignore `build` directories that are **exactly one level deep** inside your repo. So for instance files inside `build` and `foo/bar/build` won't be ignored.

If you need more fine grained control, you can always add specific directories to exclude but also not to exclude using `!` as a prefix.

Comment: I've tried all sorts of variations on this and can't get `git add .` on a bare repo to ignore a directory and all files in all subdirectories of that directory. I have tried `dirname/`, `dirname/*`, `dirname/**`, `dirname/*/*`, even in desperation `dirname/*/*/*`, `dirname/*/*/*/*`, `dirname/*/*/*/*/*`.

Comment: Thank you @Simon, so it must be something else. I don't mean --bare. I run `git init` then `git add --all .` (with or without --all) in my directory full of source files and `.gitignore` and it includes every non-empty subdirectory under my named directory. I'm using 1.9.4.msysgit.1 Solved it for now by removing the folders then re-adding them after indexing, thought I'd misunderstood the docs or syntax.

Comment: Guess this'll need some more digging to provide enough info to diagnose, but thanks for reassuring me I'm not on the wrong track.

Comment: Seems you actually have to remove the directory and re-add before it takes effect. That's what happened to me too.