# Ignore multiple .idea folders from git repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ignore

I've been using Git to work on a bunch of school projects lately. Before this, I used to have dropbox and store my IntelliJ projects there, but since I learned about version control, I never went back.

My repository consists of a folder that stores **all my projects** (it's not just one project).

Since I started using branches to better organize what I'm doing, I've been struggling with conflicts when merging branches to master. This happens because of the IDE settings stored inside every project's folder (.idea/).

I've been trying to find a way to add them to .gitignore, but since there's multiple .idea/ folders, I can't find a viable solution for this. What would be the best approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15057742/4694621

Comment: So how would that work out in this case?
/foo/bar/project_name/.idea/

Like this?

Comment: Make each project a separate repository.