# How to gitignore files under sub directroies

Tags: gitignore

How to git ignore files under sub directories. We have lots of files which we would like to ignore under sub directories.

```
(e.g. db/schema.rb or config/database.yml)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
db/schema.rb
db/*
!db/*/
```

first will ignore the schema.rb
The mixture of second and third will ignore all files in db/ but unignore all directories in db/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
*/*.rb
*/*.yml
```

to your `.gitignore`

More info here: [Git ignore sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/git-ignore-sub-folders)