# How to Ignore only subfolders within a Given folder

Tags: git, gitignore

Suppose my Code Base is like this:

```
├── index.php
├── _application
|   ├── controllers
|   └── Views
└── _jobs
    ├── report.js
    ├── report.html
    ├──_foo
    |  ├──001....
    |  ├──002....
    └──_bar
       ├──001....
       ├──002....
```

Here foo & bar are folders within the jobs folder, and there could be any number of folders, and I don't know their names in advance.

Using GitIgnore, I want to ignore all folders within 'jobs' folder, but not the files that are present there.

I have looked at [How to ignore all subfolders in a folder with .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264102/how-to-ignore-all-subfolders-in-a-folder-with-gitignore), but the solution given there ignores the files in the job folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `!/jobs/*.*`, it means, don't ignore anything with an extension which means they are files

Comment: Beware if you have files without any extension in their name.