# How can I ignore subfiles in .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a lot of subfolders and files like `node_modules>yargs-parser>README.md`. And I wrote `node_modules` in `.gitignore` file but when I change something in a file like `README.md`, git is not ignoring the changes. How can I ignore?

Comment: What do you mean by "git is not ignoring the changes"? Did you already commit the file to the repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: your gitignore should contain `node_modules/`. Also if the file is already added to git, it cannot be ignored. Remove the file from git and it will be ignored in the future

Comment: I mean I want to ignore all files in the node_modules folder. And yes I committed.

Comment: That's not what "ignore" means.

Comment: `node_modules/` means "ignore all the folders not files" and `node_modules` means ignore all the folders and files and I wrote `node_modules`. You can check Amir: https://labs.consol.de/development/git/2017/02/22/gitignore.html

Comment: Ahh I will ask something, .gitignore files ignores only the files that I will add not I already added right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you are trying to ignore is already on the index, you need to remove it first with `git rm --cached <file>` then you can ignore it in `.gitignore`

Answer (score -1):

Your .gitignore file should be ideally on the root, along with .git folder. For various other examples, see the thread: [Git ignore sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/git-ignore-sub-folders).

Check if you have spelling error or file permission issue on .gitignore file.

The file itself should should be committed.

Answer (score -2):

to ignore everything inside you can add:

```
node_modules/*
```