# git add all subfolders and files excluding one subfolder

Tags: git

I have a directory structure like this for `dr1`:

```
.
├── dr2
│   ├── hi.txt
│   └── inputs
│       ├── anotherbigfile.big
│       └── bigfile.big
├── dr3
│   ├── bye.txt
│   ├── inputs
│   │   ├── anotherbigfile.bigfile
│   │   └── bigfile.bigfile
│   └── small.txt
└── dr4
    └── bye.txt
```

My `dr1` is a git repo with `.gitignore` with the following contents:

`inputs/`

I want to stage everything in `dr1` , I mean all sub-directories and all files , I just want to not stage, commit and push the `inputs` directory in every sub-directory `dr2` `dr3` `dr4`. These contain big files and I don't them in github.

I did this `git add .` from `dr1` but I am having a problem since only the sub-directories are being staged but not the contents, so in my repo I only have empty directories, only the `dr4` sub directory works since there is no folder with `inputs` there.
What's wrong here ? I thought `git` would ignore only the sub-directory `input` but the rest of the directory would be staged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to git ignore subfolders / subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/how-to-git-ignore-subfolders-subdirectories)

Comment: I can't reproduce on my machine. Did you post the complete content of your `.gitignore` ? Run `git check-ignore -v **/*` to check if the other files are skipped because of some ignore rules.

Comment: "only the sub-directories are staged" doesn't make much sense : git doesn't track empty directories. Are these directories submodules ? or symbolic links on your file system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wildcards](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

You can add the next lines to your `.gitignore` file:

```
dr2/inputs/
dr3/inputs/
```

If you don't want to be specific and quite sure that you won't need to commit any `input` subfolder in the future than you can use:

```
**/inputs/
```

in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: hum ok makes sense. why the double asterisk `**` instead of a single one ?

Comment: @alex `**` matches any character zero or more times, including `/`. So it will ignore the `inputs` folder in *any* subdirectory.
You can replace it with `*` if you want to ignore only `inputs` subfolders of your upper-level subfolders.

Comment: What's the output for the `git status` command? And what your `.gitignore` look like?

Comment: nothing to commit is the output. and my `.gitignore` is dr2/inputs/
dr3/inputs/

Comment: I use `git add .` from `dr1` but it's still not tracking after the `gitignore` modification

Comment: That's weird. It looks like git doesn't see any not ignored files. Can you please modify any not ignored file and tell me what's `git status` output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225307/discussion-between-valerii-boldakov-and-alex).