# How to setup gitignore to track specific folders/files multiple levels down?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to set up a repository for multiple projects that uses Visual Studio.

I'm using a laptop and a desktop, but VS seems to have issues when stuff is on different drives (VS is installed on C drive for both computers, but on my desktop, my projects and external library are on the D drive while they are on the C drive for my laptop).

I want to track just the `.cpp` and `.h` source files, but I also want to keep the file structure so I don't have to manually move files around every time I pull from the repo, so I want to track the parent `src` folder and its parent (the project folder) as well. I don't want to have to add in another line to the gitignore for every project I add.

The files would be organized something like this...

```
-root
  -.gitignore
  -project1/
    -bin/
    -src/
      -main.cpp
      -foo.cpp
      -foo.h
    -project1.sln
    -project1.vcxproj
    -donttrack2.txt
  -project2/
    -bin/
    -src/
      -main.cpp
      -bar.cpp
      -bar.h
    -project2.sln
    -project2.vcxproj
  -donttrack.txt
```

I've tried [looking at the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder) but I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May depend on your Git version, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/how-to-git-ignore-subfolders-subdirectories

Comment: Thanks for the response. It shouldn't be that, given that I'm trying to set this up on my laptop and installed Git only hours prior.

Comment: Have you tried **/project2/?

Comment: I'm trying to set it up so I can avoid needing to add in an extra line for every project. Ideally I just want to have it so it just takes the src folder and its files because every project going in this repo will have a different project name but will always have a src folder directly under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gitignore, you can first specify to ignore all files

```
*/*.*
*/*/*.*
*/*/*/*.*
```

etcetera (do not do this with directories, though, because you cannot undo ignored directories)

Afterwards, you undo the ignoring of files in src folders:

```
!src/*
!*/src/*
!*/*/src/*
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I needed, thank you. What does the !*/*/src/* do though? It doesn't seem to have changed anything after doing !*/src/* .

Comment: That was for in case your src dir could also be nested deeper.

Comment: Remark: VonC's strategy of first blacklisting everything, then whitelisting folders and then whitelisting "the right" files is more elegant. than my hack to directly blacklist only files (with an extension)

Comment: Hey late reply but I'm trying to apply the same logic to some other files in bin/data, bin is located in the same folder as src, so I tried replacing "src" with "data", "bin/data", "bin/data/images", and "images", but it's not working. In this case, I want to track some files in bin/data/images, but later I might add some files into bin/data (outside of images). I couldn't figure out how to get it working with VonC's method either.

Comment: Probably the bin folder is ignored itself. First make that visible and then only bin/data

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

To exclude files (or all files) from the root folder of your repository, except `.cpp`, you would do:

```
*
!*/
!*.cpp
!*.h
```

Meaning: you need to whitelist folders first, before being able to exclude from gitignore files.

Double-check with [`git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Comment: @jthill Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To make any sense of any of this, you need to realize two things:

1. Git *never* "tracks" *any* folder.
2. The word *track* has a *very specific meaning* and has very little—almost nothing, but a little bit more than *entirely* nothing—to do with `.gitignore` files.

The very name `.gitignore` is misleading.  These are not files that Git will *ignore*.  These are:

- files that, if untracked, en-masse `git add` operations should not cause to become tracked;
- files that, when untracked, `git status` should not *complain* about; and
- files that, when they are to be clobbered by certain Git operations, Git should sometimes feel free to clobber them even if they would normally be considered "precious".

(The last case is complex.  It refers to the situation that occurs when, e.g., you've typed in a `git switch` or `git checkout` command, and under Git's normal rules, this command would be rejected on the grounds that it will destroy some file content that Git has not saved anywhere, so Git won't be able to help you get the content back.  This is mostly a problem when some file *wasn't* listed in `.gitignore` at one point, so that it became "tracked" at that point and got committed, and now *is* listed in `.gitignore` and isn't in almost all commits, but *is* in some old ones where it shouldn't be, and *is* a precious file like some kind of active database.  You're unlikely to run into this case.  There's no fix for it anyway.  Multiple people have tried to fix this, including me, and nobody has succeeded yet.)

Let's address *tracked file* first because it's actually quite simple.  You just have to buy into Git's world-view—which **you have to do anyway if you are going to use Git**, so read this next part thoroughly.

#### Git's index AKA staging area

The main bulk of almost every Git repository is a database full of Git commits and other objects.  This database is, in effect, append-only:<sup>1</sup> you *add new commits* to it.  If something isn't right, you *add another commit* in which you've corrected whatever was wrong.  There is literally no Git command to *remove* items from this database.<sup>2</sup>

The actual content of any commit is frozen for all time as soon as that commit exists.  (Git *needs* this property to make its hashing scheme work; and Git needs its hashing scheme to make distributed version control work.  It's not particularly uncommon for version control systems to have this read-only property in the first place, though.)  So the files that are stored in a commit—every commit stores a full snapshot of every file, using clever *sharing* tricks to avoid storing the same *content* twice—aren't the files that you can actually see and edit.  Instead, the committed files are a sort of archive, like a tarball or zip file or WinRAR or whatever.

This means that Git will *extract* the files *from* a commit for you to work on them.  Most version control systems are like this: you pick a commit (or some version of some file) and the VCS extracts that commit (or that file) into a work area.  So far, so what: this is the same as any other VCS.

Here's where things get weird and different in Git: when Git extracts all the files *from* a commit, it *keeps a copy* (in the internal, compressed-and-de-duplicated format) in an area that Git has three names for: the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.

So when you extract some commit, there are in fact *three* copies of each file, not the two you'd expect:

- there's a frozen-for-all-time archived copy in the commit;
- there is this weird exclusive-to-Git copy in Git's index / staging-area; and
- there is a usable copy that you can see and work on / with.

When you choose to make a *new* commit, though, Git *completely ignores the usable copy of each file*.  Instead, Git uses the *index* copy of each file.

This means that whenever you modify the working copy of a file, you must run `git add` on it.  The `git add` command tells Git: *compress the working copy into the internal form, and update the index copy*.  This doesn't overwrite the committed copy.  Instead, it makes a temporary ready-to-go copy, or finds the existing duplicate.  But either way the index copy *was* ready to commit before, and *is* ready to commit now: what's changed is the *content* in the index copy.

(Because there is this third copy, you can, if you like, use something like `git add -p` to store a *different* third copy, halfway between the committed and current copy.  Some people like to use this trick to build commits on the fly, after doing a bunch of work.  But that's just a side note.)

By adding an all-new-file to this index / staging-area, you can arrange for a *new* file to be in the next commit.  By *removing* a file from this index / staging-area, you can arrange for the next commit's snapshot to *omit* that file.  And by changing a file and replacing the index copy, you can arrange for the next commit's snapshot to have the updated file.

In all cases, the index is *always* ready to be used as the *next* snapshot.<sup>3</sup>  When you run `git commit`, Git takes the index's semi-frozen files, freezes them solidly, and puts them into the new commit.  So the commit holds the files that are in Git's *index*—not the files in your working tree!

This leads us to the idea of a *tracked file*.  **A file in Git is tracked if and only if it is in Git's index right now.**  You can add files to Git's index with `git add`, and you can remove files from Git's index with `git rm`; you just have to *also* remember that, as you switch from one commit to another (by switching branch names for instance), *Git* will fill in Git's index *from the commit*.

An untracked file is therefore quite simple as well: a file that exists in your working tree, where you can see and edit it, is *untracked* if and only if that same file *is not in Git's index right now*.  If it's not in Git's index *right now* and you run `git commit` *right now*, then it isn't in the new commit either, and that's basically all there is to it.  You decide which files will be in commits, and which won't, by deciding which files are to be in Git's index *right now*—which you control, directly (`git add`, `git rm`) and indirectly (operations that check out commits or otherwise affect Git's index).

---

<sup>1</sup>There are, of course, some maintenance commands that can clean it out, or you can do the standard thing of "dump out old database, load new database excluding the parts we don't want to copy".

<sup>2</sup>The `git gc` and `git prune` commands are the maintenance commands alluded to in footnote 1.  You don't tell them "remove object O" for some object ID, though: instead, you carefully arrange for object O to be *unreferenced*, then run `git gc` to discard the *unreferenced objects*.  So it's a rather indirect way to do this.  In general, you don't do it at all: you let Git run `git gc --auto` whenever *Git* thinks it would be profitable to do this kind of housecleaning.  You let Git generate "garbage" (unused objects) on purpose, the way Git does in general, and you let Git clean up after itself when Git thinks it's smart, and that takes care of everything.

<sup>3</sup>During a conflicted merge, the index holds more than one copy of each conflicted file.  At this time `git commit` or `git write-tree` will note that you can't make a commit, because the index holds conflicts.  So it's a slight overstatement to say that the index always holds the next commit's snapshot, because sometimes you can't get Git to write out the index.  But even in that case, the index does hold the next snapshot: you just can't make the snapshot.

---

#### The `.gitignore` rules

A file that *is* in Git's index *will be in your next commit*, unless you remove it from Git's index.  Listing such a file in `.gitignore` has no effect (unless and until you remove it from Git's index of course).

Git's index *cannot hold folders*.<sup>4</sup>  This is why Git commits cannot hold folders: Git builds the commits' snapshots from the index, and the index can't hold a folder, so there are no folders in commits.  Commits contain files with long names like `path/to/file`, as that's what's in Git's index.  Git will *make* OS-style folders as needed, to handle this.

The `.gitignore` rules *do* understand files vs folders, though, as they work on the *working tree* files.  Remember our three bullet points from above: listing files in `.gitignore` is about *preventing* them from becoming tracked, and *preventing* complaints about them being untracked.  Untracked files are, by definition, files in your working tree that aren't in Git's index.  So `.gitignore` is about working trees, and working trees *do* have folder-and-file structure.

Now, Git *reads* your working tree recursively.  That is, Git uses OS-level operations to read the top level of the working tree: it opens that folder (directory) and scans all the names in it.  Those names are:

- file names, or
- subdirectory / folder names, or
- some third kind of thing that Git should ignore anyway.

For *file* names, Git will check to see if this *file* (a) isn't already in Git's index and (b) should be ignored.  If so, en-masse "add all" operations will *skip* the file and `git status` operations won't *complain about* the file.

For *folder* names, well, they're already always not in Git's index, so we just get the answer to "(b) should be ignored": if so, en-masse "add all" operations *don't bother to look inside the folder* (and `git status` also doesn't look inside for complaint purposes).

That's why an ignored *folder* always ignores all the files *within* the folder: Git never get around to looking!  That's all there is to it.

When it comes to writing `.gitignore` rules, the simple trick to making sure Git always looks inside *every* folder is to use:

```
!*/
```

as a rule, close to or right at the end of a `.gitignore` file.  This rule consists of `*` (meaning any and all names) followed by `/` (meaning, only if they're directories / folder names), and prefixed with `!` (meaning, do not ignore).  So Git will search inside this folder.  That's it: that's all there is to it; this *completely disables* the "don't look inside" optimization.

---

<sup>4</sup>Attempts to put them in there result in Git storing *gitlink* objects instead.  See also [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)

---

#### The "don't look inside" optimization is important for speed

If you disable this optimization, Git will always look inside every nested folder (up to discovering a submodule anyway).  If you have a lot of deeply nested folders that *should* be ignored, making Git short-circuit the whole process by not looking inside the top level one of these can make a huge difference in `git status` and `git add .` speed, because searching directories tends to be one of the slowest things that Git does.

So, use this big hammer with caution.  It may affect efficiency.  Of course, if you have no ignore-able folders in the first place, there's no efficiency to be gained by ignoring them, and you should go ahead and use the big hammer.